# Optimized way to check the data existence in mysql table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two Models as below

```
Class Scheme < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :navs, :foreign_key => :schemeCode, :primary_key => :schemeCode
end

Class Nav < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :scheme, :foreign_key => :schemeCode, :primary_key => :schemeCode
end
```

Both are connected through schemeCode, I need to insert millions of navs to Nav model , I am using mass insertion as below.

```
widgets.each do |record|
navs.push "('#{record["N1"]}','#{record["N3"]}','#{record["N4"].round(8)}')"
  noOfRecords += 1
  if(noOfRecords > 100000)
    sql = "INSERT INTO navs (`schemeCode`, `navDate`, `navValue`) VALUES #{navs.join(", ")}"
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute sql
    navs = []
    noOfRecords = 1
  end
end
```

widgets is data coming from DBF file. now I need to push the Nav only if the particular scheme code is present in scheme table. I thought of two way to do it.

1) One is checking for schemeCode availability in Schemes table before pushing the navs to array for mass insert -> Which is very expensive , since for millions of records , it will query millions of time.

2) Pulling all Schemecode in an array and checking across the array for the schemeCode for presence before pushing , it will be max 2K to 3K schemes in total. -> I am not sure about its performance , since it need to iterate array more than million times.

Please help me with best possible method to handle this situation.

Comment: How are you getting that `widgets`? If you have millions of record the it's better to use mysql scripts(using table to table dump or write triggers to load data) than doing it in Ruby.

Comment: As mentioned , widgets is the data coming from file. I can't understand your point , how can I cross check with another table before pushing if I am doing mysql triggers dump.

Comment: My point is, if you have that file then load it in temp db first and then try to load it in the main db with table to table using conditions or triggers. Even Ruby script for such scenarios would be slower.